# What is the word for someone who all his classmates leave him alone

Tags: word-choice

What is the word used to describe someone who all classmates ignore him and leave him alone. I think it is some kind of bullying and we might say the person was banned from the class but I think there might be a better word out there.

Comment: Bear in mind that ***ostracize*** is a fairly "upmarket" word (some people might not know it, and some might think it's a bit "formal", depending on context). There are lots of synonyms, but if you want to be sure *everyone* understands your text you could just use, for example, ***ignored***. Or for a bit more street cred you could use the slightly colloquial *They **blanked** him.*

Comment: Did he do anything wrong and this is like a social punishment? Anyway, the first two words that came to my mind were: *rejected* and *boycotted*. Their synonyms should be more or less useful.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Yes, he did something wrong and that served as a social punishment. **Boycott** is a good one too, I think.

Comment: Do you want the activity (shun, ostracise, ignore) or the word for the person (loner, outcast, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excellent verb in this context is **shun.** [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/shun) has:

> verb (used with object), shunned, shunning.
>
> > 1. to keep away from (a place, person, object, etc.), from motives of dislike, caution, etc.; take pains to avoid.

For example (from [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/shun)):

> After many attempts at being polite, you and your friends began to **shun** the obnoxious woman who never let you get a word in edgewise.